# Dart language usage

Tags: dart

I am new to Dart and I have a question regarding casting.

I am trying to cast a MouseEvent.offset Point to a Point. I understand that int is not a subtype of double. So what is the correct way to coerce an int into a double without having to do something like:

```dart
Point p = event.offset; 
Point<double> dp = new Point<double>(p.x + 0.0, p.y + 0.0);
```

As expected when I try to do something like:

```dart
double x = p.x as double;
```

an exception is thrown.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call toDouble.

```
 p.x.toDouble()
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that. Lol. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Although the Dart Editor doesn't suggest **toDouble** as an option but it works.